# How to fix huffman tree

Tags: huffman-code

I am using Huffman Encoding to compress radar data. The data arrives at a rate of 30 fps. Each frame is divided into 9x64 data chunks and this chunk is compressed at one time.

I do not want to transfer the huffman tree along with the compressed data for decoding. Is there any way the tree can be fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply take a large amount of your data, generate a Huffman code for that, and ... that's it. Just use that code on both sides.

If you want to get fancier, you can see if your data clusters statistically, and generate a handful of Huffman codes, one for each cluster. Then just send a few bits at the front of the data to select the Huffman code to use.